# Rolling sum of list elements, lapply and reduce in R

Tags: r

This should be easier than it is for me, quite sad. I'm trying to learn a basic skill that I then apply to a large list.

I have a simple list `thr2 <- list(1,2,3,4,5)` and want to sum elements 1:3, 2:4, 3:5.

I tried `thr3 <- lapply(seq(3,5), function(i) Reduce("+",thr2[i-2:i]))` thinking that it would apply reduce to 3-2:3, 4-2:4, and 5-2:5.

But instead it produces this, which is obviously not what I want

```
> thr3
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 3

[[3]]
[1] 6
```

Fell like I'm missing something basic.

Comment: Could you please show your answer, so it will help others

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. it was order of operations on i-2

```
thr3 <- lapply(seq(3,5), function(i) Reduce("+",thr2[(i-2):i]))
```